# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{6n+2}{3n+5} = 2$

Tags: limits

By the definition of a limit (using Given an $\epsilon > 0$), prove

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n+2}{3n+5} = 2$$

Proof:

Given epsilon>0 , let N = 1/(3epsilon)

if n >= N, then absolute value of [(6n+2)/(3n+5) -2] = absolute value of [ 12/ (3n+5)] < 1/3n <= 1/3N = epsilon

Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n+2}{3n+5} = 2$$

Is that first proof correct?
as well as,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2 -2n-3}{2n^2-1} = \frac12$$

n goes to infinity

I'm pretty stuck right now, any help would be great.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, $$\left|\frac{6n+2}{3n+5}-2\right|<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow n>\frac{8-5\varepsilon}{3\varepsilon}$$
Hence, $\forall\varepsilon>0$, choose $N=max\{\frac{8-5\varepsilon}{3\varepsilon},0\}$. Then $\forall n\geq N$, $\left|\frac{6n+2}{3n+5}-2\right|<\varepsilon$, which ends your proof.